# PHP Mysql timestamp wrong format

Tags: php, mysql, time, format, timestamp

I've got this in as my php-code on 2 sides:

```
date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Berlin");
$time_stamp = date('Y-m-d h:i:sa');
```

I insert the value at the first page, and at the second I update the join_timestamp.

But the time-formats are different and I don't know why.

[image]

Comment: Post the PHP code where you insert and update (click "edit" below your question, paste the code, save the question).

Comment: FYI You should use 24 hour format `H` or else how do you know the difference between 8:45 in the morning and 8:45 at night?  Also no need for the `a` as the db column doesn't use that.